# 256M in phpinfo but still fatal error at 48M in Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, memory-limit

My phpinfo indicates that my memory_limit is at 256M. But I keep getting fatal errors when I install a module, try to copy targets (e.g. more than 300) to a target-list.

I also did add the following line to the index.php at the start.

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```

no help.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a file in your sugar home directory with `<?php phpinfo();?>` and check what that states about memory limit. The value might be overridden in the .htaccess file.

Another possiblity is that the module itself sets the php memory limit at some point. Try to search the module's source code.